# For loop is not working in negative values in PHP

Tags: php

This loop showing empty page i want to run it til -60.

```
for($i = 6; $i <= -60; $i-=6){         
    echo $i;   echo '</br>';
}
```

Comment: What would be the output for this loop?

Comment: Try this `for($i = 6; $i <= -60; $i--){         
    echo $i;   echo '</br>';
}`

Comment: shouldn't it be `$i >= -60`?

Comment: When `$i` is e.g. `-70` then `$i <= -60` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `>=`, not `<=`:

```
for($i = 6; $i >= -60; $i-=6){

   echo $i;   echo '</br>';

}
```

Note that `>=` is **greater than or equal**, and `<=` is **less than or equal**.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement and code are contradictory. Starting from `$i = 6` and then check if **`$i` is less than or equal to -60** which is false. Rewrite your code like this.

```
for($i = 6; $i >= -60; $i-=6){         
    echo $i;   echo '</br>';
}
```

Output as expected:

```
6
0
-6
-12
-18
-24
-30
-36
-42
-48
-54
-60
```

Answer (score -1):

People are usually hard on newbies, but we've gotta be patient, we were all newbies once. And I think OP is in need of something more than just answer to his [trivial] question.

### Good stuff that could have been done before asking the question

1. You should have gone through a basic PHP course (like [learn-php.org](http://www.learn-php.org/) or [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php))
2. You should have tried a similar chapter of a different course if the question arose during such a course
3. You should have read the StackOverflow guidelines towards [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
4. You should have read about [PHP for loop](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php) and [PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
5. You could have read about [PHP syntax quidelines](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) so that you wouldn't have two `echo` statements on the same line (and absence of spaces where they are needed).

   > **2.3. Lines**
   >
   > > There MUST NOT be more than one statement per line.

Comment: [Two statements on one line works just fine.](https://3v4l.org/htbnk). Guidelines !== rules. Also, this does not answer the question even though it is well intentioned.

Comment: @vascowhite Thought that answering a trivial question will not entail in person continuing to ignore manuals or systematic learning and asking more questions like this is quite novel, but I respectfully disagree. Cheers!